# Как настроить относительный путь Webpack React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Есть подобный импорт
`import avatar from "../../../../../../src/img/ava.jpg";`
А хотелось бы настроить вебпак так, чтоб все картинки из любой директории проекта импортировались именно из папки img вот так: `import avatar from "img/ava.jpg";"`
Знаю, что это настраивается в webpack.config.js но как???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что Вам нужно, называется "алиасы". В документации вебпака есть описание как это сделать (см https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias).

Вкратце, в webpack.config.js в секцию module.exports добавить параметр resolve (если его нет)

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/'),
    },
  },
```

Дальше в модулях можете использовать обозначенные алиасы типа

```
import Component1 from 'Components/component1';
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Добавил в конфиг, но ругается, что не находит путь к файлу. Наверное мой __dirname имеет другой путь и `src/myFolder/` не сработал. Хотя __dirname это абсолютный путь... Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема? В любом случае спасибо за наводку на Alias.

Comment: Попробуйте установить `$ npm install file-loader --save-dev` и добавить в конфиг в блок rules такое `{ test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, use: [{loader: 'file-loader', options: {}}] }`